# Wordpress: Using php or jquery to go back when url is stored in data attribute

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have taken over a WordPress site in which I need to add back buttons within the site.

The browser url is always the same and you have to use navigations buttons that are built-in.

A link is set up as:

```
<a href="#" data="url">Link text</a>
```

When someone clicks the link it loads the new page/post within the div container.

I need to find a way to have a user go back to the previous "page" when clicking this custom back button. Like somehow remember the previous page's data attribute then using that to go back.

I really have no idea how to approach this...

Comment: How is anyone supposed to bookmark anything if url never changes? Also horrible for SEO. Sounds like the 1990's all over again with frames

Comment: @charlietfl I agree but again, I'm just taking over the site and do not have time to redo the entire thing...

Comment: How does page currently work? Hard for us to know what to tell you without understanding how page works in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript history method like this:

```
<a href="#" data-url="http://previous-url" id='goBack'>Link text</a>

<script>
$('#goBack').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url_to_go = $(this).attr('data-url');
    window.location.href = url_to_go;
});
</script>
```

Comment: this takes the user back to the previous url.

I need the user to go back to the previous "page" which loads in the same window.

ALL links open in the same window (in a div) so the browser url always reads the same for the site no matter when you are.

Comment: @forwardslashend so you need to redirect the user to the url given in the data attributes?

Comment: Yes say I'm currently on the page with url: "url-1" (which is set in data NOT href), then click on <a href="#" data="url-2">Link 1</a> 

Now that I am at url-2, I click a back button to go back to url-1.

Comment: So you haven't track of previous url. I think you should have to store previous url in the anchor data-attribute. then my updated code will work fine for you.

Comment: @forwardslashend navigation concept of all in same url is truly bizarre and makes site useless to outside world and horrible for users....if you at least change the hash and use history api will make site user friendly